# Merge two arrays, but not like array_merge

Tags: php

I have two arrays in php, both have a date value with 7 days. The same in each. The rest of the content of the array differs. They look a little like this:

Array #1:

```
 [0]
    [date] => 2012-05-01
    [value 1] => 3
```

Array #2:

```
 [0]
    [date] => 2012-05-01
    [value 2] => 3
```

I'd like to merge them to get this:

```
 [0]
    [date] => 2012-05-01
    [value 1] => 3
    [value 2] => 3
```

Right now I'm using this slop:

```
$i = 0;
$full_array = array();
foreach ($array_1 as $a) {
    foreach ($array_2 as $b) {
        if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {
            $full_array[$i] = $a;
            $full_array[$i] += $b;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I can turn that guy into a function but before I do I figured I'd check to see if there was a better way. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me `array_merge($array1, $array2)` in this case would actually return what you want, since: "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one."

Comment: @Jeroen - [Indeed](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EffnpM)

Comment: That's not what I'm getting. When I `print_r` I'm getting them stacked. The code in that codepad script contains two arrays. I have two associative arrays.

Comment: @Jeroen, the arrays have numeric keys at the top level. `array_merge` isn't recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by comments, you can use `array_merge()` for this. But you will have loop the outer array in order to get it to work, which would be better done with a `for` loop so you reference both at once:

```
for ($i = 0, $len = count($array_1), $full_array = array(); $i < $len; $i++) {
  $full_array[$i] = array_merge($array_1[$i], $array_2[$i]);
}
```